# How removing an appended element after a DIV is toggled using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to append an element on a DIV that has toggle function. But when I click on toggle again(when it is toggled) the element that I appended previously is appended again. And I end up with two equal elements.

Observation: Consider that I need to append more than one element. And remove more than one element appended too.

Example:

DIV A 
      Element A

My actions in Javascript using JQuery:
1) Toggle DIV A and Append Element A = div A and element A show up.
2) Toggle DIV A = div A and element A disappear.
3) Toggle DIV A and Append Element A again =

```
DIV A
   Element A
   Element A
```

I want only one Element A.(That's the problem, toggle doesn't remove my previous appended element)

My code is something like that:

```
$("#DIVA").toggle(function(){
    var my_div_to_be_appended = "<div>my div<div>";
    var my_div_to_be_appended2 = "<div>my div2<div>";
    $("DIVA").append(my_div_to_be_appended);
    $("DIVA").append(my_div_to_be_appended2);           
});
```

Comment: and what instead of append content make content visible by toggle?

Comment: How about adding the "Element A" and hiding it, and then the toggle just needs to show/hide it, simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easy, instead of using append, use html.

```
$("#DIVA").toggle(function(){
    var my_div_to_be_appended = "<div>my div<div>";
    // This will replace the content every time the toogle function is called.
    $("DIVA").html(my_div_to_be_appended);            
});
```

Comment: It works if I have only one element to append, that's not the case. I will update my informations. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If your **DIVA** is empty then sch4v4's solution is perfect for you, but if that div already has some content in it and you cannot use **.html()** 
then another simple solution to your problem is to keep another empty div inside of your **$("#DIVA")** instead of appending itself.
Take the following example

```
<div id="DIVA">
  <!-- Some other elements here - if any -->
  <div id="my_dynamic_div"></div>
</div>
```

and then in your jquery code

```
$("#DIVA").toggle(function(){
    var my_div_to_be_appended = "<div>my div<div>";
    $("#my_dynamic_div").html(my_div_to_be_appended);            
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It works if I have only one element to append, that's not the case. I will update my informations. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok np, you had mentioned that you want only one element and previous elements removed, so that's the solution for the mentioned problem. Let me know if i can help you in a different case.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions, for now, I'm doing this as a solution:

```
$("#DIVA").toggle(function(){
    var my_div_to_be_appended = "<div>my div<div>";
    var my_div_to_be_appended2 = "<div>my div2<div>";
    $("DIVA").html(my_div_to_be_appended + my_div_to_be_appended2);           
});
```